# GUID nibble order in WiX versus Registry

Tags: wix, registry, guid

This is probably something silly, but I haven't found out why it is...

I have several GUIDs specified in my WiX install source. For example:

```
<Product Id="...-57725972C7B2" ...
```

After an install, I was having trouble finding them in the registry until I realized they all had swapped nibbles. So, the way the GUID appears in the registry is:

```
...752795277C2B
```

I haven't been able to find anywhere that describes this, so I'm wondering why does it do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save space in the registry. (MSI was developed in the late 90s and supported Windows 9x, where registry space was severely limited.) It's called a packed GUID, sometimes compressed GUID. It's not documented in the MSI SDK but there are semi-official posts, such as https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2009/12/17/how-to-convert-an-office-guid-or-office-patch-guid-to-a-compressed-guid/.